# redux reducer vs action

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Newbie question regarding reducer vs action. [From redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html):

> Actions describe the fact that something happened, but don’t specify
>   how the application’s state changes in response.

and

> Given the same arguments, reducer should calculate the next state and
>   return it. No surprises. No side effects. No API calls. No mutations.
>   Just a calculation.

So if we consider the following scenario:

1. User can place points on a map and get route between those points.
2. When user first clicks on a map this is his starting point. When he clicks for the second time - this is his ending point. Consequent clicks add points between the previous point and end location.
3. After each point is added (except for the first one) route must be calculated between new point and previous point. So if i have S -> A -> F and add point B (S -> A -> B -> F) two routes must be calculated A -> B and B -> F

So we kind of have two side effects upon adding any 3+ point:

- New point is placed not at the end of the list
- New route must be calculated to the Finish point.

If i model my Point structure as this:

```
 // typescript
interface Point {
  coordinates;
  routeTo?;
}
```

Am I correct to perform item position calculation and route retrieval in Actions, eg:

```
  // pseudo code
    export function addMapPoint(newPoint) {
      return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const {points} = getState();
        const position = getInsertPosition(points, newPoint)
        dispatch(addPoint(newPoint, position));
        if (points.length >= 2) {
          const previousPoint = getPreviousPoint(points, position);
          calculateRoute(newPoint, previousPoint).then(route => {
            dispatch(updateRoute(newPoint, route))
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

To me this somehow contradicts to the "but don’t specify how the application’s state changes" - because from action i'm specifying where to insert my new point.
I could calculate the insert position in reducer, but then how do i fetch route data for the Finish point?
What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming we have a `calculateRoute` function that accepts two points, and returns a promise that resolved the route between them.

First, let's create a simple action creator so we know our points are stored correctly:

```
let addPoint = (point, index) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_POINT',
        point: point,
        index: index
    }
}
```

Then, let's handle this action in the reducer:

```
let reducer = (state = { points: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_POINT':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                points: [
                    ...state.points.slide(0, action.index),
                    action.point,
                    ...state.points.slide(action.index + 1)
                ]
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Now, after the users add a point, we create an action using `addPoint` and dispatch it, so far so good, but this is the easy stuff.

The structure I strive for is to have a routes list in my reducer too, so let's extend it to support that:

```
let reducer = (state = { points: [], routes: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_POINT':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                points: [
                    ...state.points.slide(0, action.index),
                    action.point,
                    ...state.points.slide(action.index + 1)
                ]
            });
        case 'UPDATE_ROUTES':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                routes: action.routes
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And the action creator will be:

```
let updateRoutes = (routes) => {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_ROUTES',
        routes: routes
    }
}
```

Please notice we're overriding the entire routes collection. For now it's OK, but probably in a production system you would want to optimize it a little bit.

Now we actually need to write some logic. I will assume a convenient assumption that we have a `calculateRoutes` that gets a collection of points, and returns a promise that resolves a list of respective routes, each route will be an object, containing two points and the actual route. Having said that, our `thunk` will now look like this:

```
addPointAndUpdateRoutes = (point, index) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        // First, update the point list
        dispatch(addPoint(point, index));

        // Now, recalculate routes
        calculateRoutes(getState().points)
            .then(routes => dispatch(updateRoutes(routes));
    };
};
```

Which is way nicer in my opinion.

---

Now, off course that assuming we have a magical `calculateRoutes` function is not a serious assumption, though it's not a super hard task to implement this function in an optimized manner (meaning actually send the server only routes that we did not calculate before, etc). **BUT** this is just logic and **NOT** the state of the application, thus, as long as you keep the "contract" defined by the store and reducers, you are free to implement it any way you'd like.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So looking at your proposed `addPointAndUpdateRoutes = (point, index)` and `addPoint(point, index)` signatures - index calculation is moved to the ui? But what if i can add a point by both clicking on a map entering coordinates manually ?. Regarding `calculateRoutes` what if i have 100 points? or 200 ? each time loop through the whole list, check some cache (yet another state...) and if the user can always start from scratch? then i have to invalidate that cache..

Comment: I guess you can calculate the `index` in the UI, I mean adding a point between two existing points is something that can be expressed very clearly in the UI. About `calculateRoutes` - You need to have a memoized function, meaning if it already calculated a route, it would return it immediately, This implementation needs to be on your client and on your server. If a user has 100 or 1000 or even 5000 points, it doesn't really matter, it will happen pretty fast as long as it's not really calculated. Anyway, if you support 100 points, you'd have to calculate them no matter the UI implementation.

Comment: well my point was that i might have two, four or five different places where i can add a Point. And the logic stays the same - if first point - add, second - add it, if third - add before last one, etc. So this logic should not be duplicated in each UI component. If i use smart calculateRoutes approach this can be done in reducer (but is it right?). Or why should i store routes separately - they cannot live without a point. And a point might not have a route if it cannot be reached which causes a side effect that Finish point might also become unreachable.

Comment: You can have five different places where a point can be added, but all these places should reference the same logic, which mustn't be in the reducer. `calculateRoutes` has nothing to do with the reducer either, except that the reducer stores its output. A point is an entity and a route is a totally different entity, that happens to hold two points.